# How to show $(a + b)^n \leq a^n + b^n$, where $a, b \geq 0$ and $n \in (0, 1]$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality, fractions, karamata-inequality

Does anyone happen to know a nice way to show that $(a+b)^n \le a^n+b^n$, where $a,b\geq 0$ and $n \in (0,1]$?  I figured integrating might help, but I've been unable to pull my argument full circle. Any suggestions are appreciated :)

Comment: Triangle Inequality. Look that up as a start (this is a generalization of the triangle inequality)

Comment: If $a = 0$ or $b = 0$, equality is easy to see. If both are $> 0$, divide by $(a+b)^n$, then you want to show that $$\biggl(\frac{a}{a+b}\biggr)^n + \biggl(\frac{b}{a+b}\biggr)^n \geqslant 1.$$ Why is that the case for $0 < n \leqslant 1$?

Answer (score 15):

We have $$ 1 = \frac{a}{a+b} +\frac{b}{a+b} \le \left(\frac{a}{a+b}\right)^n +\left(\frac{b}{a+b} \right)^n $$ for $0<n\le 1.$

Comment: Best one-liner this week.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=x^n$, where $n\in(0,1]$ and $a\geq b$.

Hence, $f$ is a concave function and $(a+b,0)\succ(a,b)$.

Thus, by Karamata $$(a+b)^n+0^n\leq a^n+b^n$$ 
and we are done!

Answer (score 1):

The cases $a=0$ is trivial. For $a\ne 0$ let $m=1/n$ and $c=a^{1/m}=a^n$ and $d=b^{1/m}=b^n.$ Then $$(a+b)^n\leq a^n+b^n\iff (c^m+d^m)^{1/m}\leq c+d\iff$$ $$\iff  c^m+d^m\leq (c+d)^m\iff 1+(d/c)^m\leq (1+d/c)^m\iff$$ $$\iff (d/c)^m\leq (1+d/c)^m-1\iff$$ $$\iff  m\int_0^{d/c}x^{m-1}dx\leq m\int_0^{d/c}(1+x)^{m-1}dx$$ which holds as $d/c\geq 0$ and $m-1\geq 0.$

Comment: I always do it the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that
$a \ge b$.
If $a = b = 0$,
the result is immediate.

If $a > 0$,
divide
$(a+b)^n \le a^n+b^n
$
by
$a^n$
to get
$(1+b/a)^n \le 1+(b/a)^n
$.

Since
$b \le a$,
$0 \le b/a \le 1$,
so this becomes
$(1+x)^n \le 1+x^n
$
where
$x = b/a$.

Let $f(x)
=1+x^n-(1+x)^n
$.

$f(0) = 0$
and
$f(1)
=2-2^n
\ge 0
$
since
$0 < n \le 1$.

$f'(x)
=nx^{n-1}-n(1+x)^{n-1}
=n(x^{n-1}-(1+x)^{n-1})
=n(\frac1{x^{1-n}}-\frac1{(1+x)^{1-n}})
$.

Since
$0 < n \le 1$,
$1-n \ge 0$
so that
$x^{1-n}
\le (1+x)^{1-n}
$
so that
$\frac1{x^{1-n}}\ge\frac1{(1+x)^{1-n}}
$
so that
$f'(x) \ge 0$.

Since
$f(0) = 0$
and
$f'(x) \ge 0$
for $0 < x\le 1$,
$f(x)
\ge 0
$
for
$0 \le x \le 1$.

Note that
the inequality goes the other way
if $n > 1$.